# Is there any way to override guard statement?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I know it looks impossible and also may get negative marks for that but still I want to know if we can do something to override the guard statement so that we can get method call whenever we call guard statement. 
For Example -

```
guard let string = testString else {
    BuggerManager.send(exType: .invalidArgumentException, exMessage: "testString is nil")
    return
}
print(string)

// it happened very rare
@IBAction func toErrorDivideHandled() {
    do {
        let some = try self.divide(x: 10, y: 0)
        print(some)
    } catch let error {
        BuggerManager.send(exType: .decimalNumberDivideByZeroException, exMessage: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

OR

Can we create global guard type method. if yes, then how can we create that. Thanks in Advance. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Can you show some example code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, I created a small framework which add exceptions in queue with one method call. where ever I call the method exception will be added in queue and after sometime it will send to server. What I am doing now is I call method in every else statement of guard. What I want is to override guard statement so that I don't have put same method in every guard else block. I hope you understand my comment. Thanks for showing your interest in this question.

Comment: What are you guarding exactly? This really sounds like an XY problem. Please show some of your guard statements.

Comment: you could write a wrapper function on top of an `guard` statement and execute your code in the wrapper.

Comment: @Sweeper Examples
https://codeshare.io/5DPW0Z

Comment: @dirtydanee I think I am  getting your point but could you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the guard statement, but you can maybe approximate what you want to do by wrapping it and using Swift's error-handling mechanism:

```
enum GuardError: Error {
    // In practice, put arguments on this case
    // that you use to describe the error
    case doesntExist
}

func guardIt<T>(_ closure: () -> T?) throws -> T {
    guard let ret = closure() else { throw GuardError.doesntExist }
    return ret
}
```

You can then use this like so:

```
let foo = try guardIt { somePossiblyNilThing }
```

In your `catch` block, you can use parameters in your enum case to send the appropriate information to `BuggerManager`.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in this question @Charles Srstka but I want some thing else.